# Stitching - ImageJ

Tags: imagej, image-stitching

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I have been using the stitching algorithms several times in the past with no issues. But right now, I always get error messages in the console - even if there is nothing wrong in the log. Then, the fused image is not displayed. I tried with different image types, or different stitching methods, but all of them lead to the same type of error message. Here is an example:

---

[ERROR] null
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find method net.imglib2.type.NativeType.createSuitableNativeImg(Lnet/imglib2/img/NativeImgFactory;[J)Lnet/imglib2/img/NativeImg;
There was a problem with the class net.imglib2.type.NativeType which can be found here:
/C:/Fiji.app/jars/imglib2-5.3.0.jar
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.imglib2.type.NativeType.createSuitableNativeImg(Lnet/imglib2/img/NativeImgFactory;[J)Lnet/imglib2/img/NativeImg;
    at net.imglib2.img.imageplus.ImagePlusImgFactory.create(ImagePlusImgFactory.java:69)
    at net.imglib2.img.imageplus.ImagePlusImgFactory.create(ImagePlusImgFactory.java:64)
    at net.imglib2.img.ImgFactory.create(ImgFactory.java:174)
    at mpicbg.stitching.fusion.OverlayFusion.createOverlay(OverlayFusion.java:176)
    at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.fuse(Stitching_Pairwise.java:481)
    at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.performPairWiseStitching(Stitching_Pairwise.java:448)
    at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.run(Stitching_Pairwise.java:299)
    at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:233)
    at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:196)
    at ij.Executer.runCommand(Executer.java:150)
    at ij.Executer.run(Executer.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
at net.imglib2.img.imageplus.ImagePlusImgFactory.create(ImagePlusImgFactory.java:69)
at net.imglib2.img.imageplus.ImagePlusImgFactory.create(ImagePlusImgFactory.java:64)
at net.imglib2.img.ImgFactory.create(ImgFactory.java:174)
at mpicbg.stitching.fusion.OverlayFusion.createOverlay(OverlayFusion.java:176)
at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.fuse(Stitching_Pairwise.java:481)
at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.performPairWiseStitching(Stitching_Pairwise.java:448)
at plugin.Stitching_Pairwise.run(Stitching_Pairwise.java:299)
at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:233)
at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:196)
at ij.Executer.runCommand(Executer.java:150)
at ij.Executer.run(Executer.java:68)
```

### at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I don't know, maybe I missed something obvious, has anyone encountered the same type of issue?
Thank you very much in advance!

Joti

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to a change in the source-code of the imglib2 library.

By reading the [documentation](https://imagej.net/Changes_from_ImgLib1_to_ImgLib2) you can see how much has changed from imglib to imglib2.

There seems to be a [FiJi bug](http://fiji.sc/bug/1061.html) filed for this.

Are you using any plugins that could be using old/broken code? Can you verify that every dependency is using the correct version of imglib?

Comment: It seems previous similar errors were associated with a lack of proper plugin updates: https://forum.image.sc/t/getting-an-error-when-trying-to-use-stitching-plugin/19357 Maybe that is your problem as well?

Comment: Thank you @ZektorH and @iarganda! I'll check this. I have been running the Fiji integrated updater, but maybe this is not enough for the plugins which are non integrated primarily with Fiji.

Comment: Hello again! I basically reinstalled Fiji and ImageJ, and I think everything was correctly updated, and now stitching works! Than you for your help!